# spring-pulsar minimum spring boot version?

Tags: spring-pulsar

The [documentation for spring-pulsar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/) contains a table documenting the compatibility matrix of supported technology versions.

At the time this question is being asked, it states that the minimum Spring Boot version is 3.2.0. But when I look at start.spring.io, the current spring boot snapshot version is 3.1.1-SNAPSHOT. There is no 3.2.0.

Is this an error in the documentation? Or are we supposed to understand from this that the spring-pulsar library is not yet production ready and will not be until the release of Spring Boot 3.2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or are we supposed to understand from this that the spring-pulsar library is not yet production ready and will not be until the release of Spring Boot 3.2.0?

Yes, this matrix is confusing. More context needs to be added to this area of the doc.

The current recommended version of Spring Pulsar is `0.2.x` ([docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-pulsar/docs/0.2.0/reference/html/)).

The version you are viewing are SNAPSHOT docs of `1.0.0` and are not quite ready for viewing. Although that is not stated in the docs.

Here is the state of the project:

- In `0.2.x` the core + Spring Boot autoconfig + Spring Cloud Stream binder all live in the `spring-pulsar` repo.
- In `1.0.0` (upcoming):

  - the core will live in `spring-pulsar`
  - the autoconfig  will live in Spring Boot repo (aiming for `3.2.0`)
  - the binder will live in Spring Cloud Stream repo (aiming for `4.1.0`)

We will be sure to:

1. Make sure the SNAPSHOT docs callout that they are in flux as they are SNAPSHOT
2. Make sure this compatibility matrix calls out the above state of the project/repos etc..

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: Created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-pulsar/issues/412

Comment: Docs are updated - hopefully it clarifies all the things (screenshots added [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-pulsar/issues/412#issuecomment-1594943005)). Thanks